# How do i transform a string to become a comma separated in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two different string inputs:

```
commas = " e@test1.com,e@test2.com , e@test1.com  ,  e@test3.com  "
spaces = " e@test1.com e@test2.com   e@test1.com     e@test3.com  "
```

And I want to create a function that produces comma separated values, and the following result:

```
expected = "e@test1.com,e@test2.com,e@test1.com,e@test3.com  "
```

Any suggestions? Maybe regex??

Comment: You really need to show us what you've tried. As is it's hard to tell if you're fishing for code.

Comment: You want to preserve the spaces at the end, but not at the beginning? It is irritating to prepare and submit an answer, only to find that another answer was already selected a mere 30 minutes after the question was posted, particularly when it was the only answer that had been received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or this:

```
string.strip.gsub(/[ ,]+/, ',')
```

Note: As in your example, if you want to preserve spaces at the end of the string, you can use this (instead of `strip`):

```
string.sub(/\A +/, '').gsub(/[ ,]+(?=[^ ,])/, ',')
```

Comment: While this does work for the OPs given input / output, please note that this may not work correctly if your strings have legitimate commas / spaces in them.

Comment: @JustinWood: Yes probably, but why do you want to have "legimate commas/spaces" in an email adresses list?

Comment: Like I said. This works for the given scenario. Just don't expect it to work for all cases.

Comment: @JustinWood, let me get this straight; you are saying that this solution might not work if a different question had been asked?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly (to preserve spacing at the end and separate words or the like with commas only), this is one way to do it:

```
def modify(string)
  string.scan(/[^\s,]+/).join(',') << string[/\s+$/]
end

modify " e@test1.com,e@test2.com , e@test1.com  ,  e@test3.com  "
  #=> "e@test1.com,e@test2.com,e@test1.com,e@test3.com  "
modify " e@test1.com e@test2.com   e@test1.com     e@test3.com  "
  #=> "e@test1.com,e@test2.com,e@test1.com,e@test3.com  "
```